# If statement needs to accept multiple forms of user input String data type

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I'm very new to Java. Currently, I'm trying to create a game of Rock Paper Scissors, which I've actually already done. My problem lies within a mechanism of trying to ask the player if they want to play at the start of the program. If so, they can enter "YES" or "yes" or "y"/"Y", if not, then "NO"/"no"/"n"/"N" and so forth.

Currently, I am storing the answer that the user gives in a String data type variable. In an "if" statement below that, I am trying to check if the answer is Yes. If so, the game initializes. If "No", the program exits. However, the boolean operator "Or" isn't quite working for me at the moment. Here's how my code is set up:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

    // Create Scanner Object
    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create variables
    String name, go;
    int gonum=0;

    System.out.printf("WELCOME TO ROCK PAPER SCISSORS. WE TAKE THIS GAME SERIOUSLY.\n\n");

    System.out.printf("USER, WHAT IS YOUR NAME?\n");
    name = get.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("\nWELCOME, %S, TO ROCK PAPER SCISSORS.", name);

    System.out.printf("\n\nDO YOU WISH TO PLAY?\n");
    go = input.nextLine();

    if(go == "YES" || go == "yes" || go == "Yes" || go == "y")
    {
        System.out.printf("LET'S PLAY SOME ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!");
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the string equals "yes" or "no" by using any of these methods.

```
e.g go.equal("no") || go.equal("yes") 

equals(Object anObject) 
   Compares this string to the specified object.
equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) 
    Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations.
```

Another way is to use the Contain boolean method

```
contains(CharSequence s) 
Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
```

e.g go.contains("y") || go.contains("n")

[More String Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: While I do appreciate the help, I am not going to lie when I tell you that I'm not sure what you are talking about here. I'm sorry.

Comment: You can either use the method "contains" or "equals to" so if(go.equals("no")){} or you can use contains which I will prefer for your game since it will apply for both input "yes" or "y".

Comment: This last part, dealing with the contains() part, is golden. Thank you.

Comment: I am really glad that you found that useful I will attach a link to reference more useful methods for String

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to check out that link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn How to compare the two Strings in java

compare the strings using `equals()` not with `==`

change `if(go == "YES")` to `if(go.equals("YES"))`

`==`  equality operator is used for compare the two Objects

Comment: I've never heard of this, but it works exactly for my uses. Thank you so much. If you don't mind elaborating, what exactly is the difference between using

'if(go == "YES")' and 'if(go.equals("YES"))'

Comment: It's Ok Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the equals     ==     operator and the "equals" method, is that the    ==    operator is a boolean operator used between two primitive data types. Such as two ints or doubles you may be doing a boolean test on. The "equals" method is a method of the String class and tests whether two Strings are alike. You would used the String "equals" method as such,    bucket.equals(mop);    . The bucket and mop variables would both hold Strings.